# Pls help translate a short sentence

Tags: translation, traditional-characters

I am looking into getting a Chinese tattoo saying “Just go with the flow” down my spine but I don’t want to trust Google translate and would much rather get the answers through here.

Answer (score 3):

**顺其自然** is the phrase you're looking for.

Even when you put it into Google:

> [image]

they want to show you results for:

> Go With The Flow (Song by Tiger Huang)

Answer (score 2):

Just go with the flow might be translated to "隨波逐流", but the meaning is a bit negative: just follow up the others or no central thought in your mind.

Something positive could be translated to "乘風而行", while the flow in the sentence could be replaced with 'wind'. The meaning is more like to love freedom or liberty without any restrictions or bindings, just go anywhere you want. This is better while you need to take it on tattoo :)

Answer (score 1):

Some more suggestions

[隨遇而安](https://zi.media/@whyhtd01com/post/cVwTmj) (idiom): not forcing, be content with whatever come your way

[隨緣](https://www.liaotuo.com/remen/suiyuan.html) (Buddhism term): not forcing, accept fate and act accordingly